# Can I update the Modified By value in Sharepoint with another value?

Tags: sharepoint

In a Sharepoint document library, I've some documents with version history. In C#, can I get the version history of a document and update the user?

The version history of the document is something line this:

```
Data                Modified By
----                -----------
doc1 changed        User X
some text           User X
```

Using C#, can I update the Modified By user value with another user?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing right now, but I think it should be possible to modify this value with object model without any problem. Just set it in your code with value you like ([UserId];#[SERVER\LoginName]) and instead of using `Update` method, use `SystemUpdate'. I'm quite sure that it works for Lists, didn't test it on Document Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the list item in oListItem, you need to set the Editor of the ListItem field by using FieldUserValue object:

```
FieldUserValue fldUser = new FieldUserValue();
fldUser.LookupId = User.Id;
clientContext.Load(fldUser);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();//or use another way to get your user

oListItem["Editor"] = fldUser;
```